# How can I collapse android gridview in bottom-sheet behavior?

Tags: android, gridview, bottom-sheet

I'm working on application such as **whats app** camera and I have some difficulties to collapse android `gridview` which in `bottomsheet behavior`.
I want to collapse when there's no longer any items to previewed and dragging top down.

Android XML code:

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:layout_marginBottom="100dp"
        android:id="@+id/main_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true">
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/drag_arrow"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:paddingBottom="40dp"
            android:paddingTop="10dp"
            android:src="@mipmap/arrow_up"
            app:layout_anchor="@+id/galleryGridView2" />

        <GridView
            android:id="@+id/galleryGridView2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="500dp"
            android:background="#44000000"
            android:columnWidth="120dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:horizontalSpacing="10dp"
            android:numColumns="auto_fit"
            android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
            android:verticalSpacing="10dp"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/bottom_sheet_behavior" />
    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

and JAVA code:

```
BottomSheetBehavior mBottomSheetBehavior;
final GridView gallery;

gallery = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.galleryGridView2);

mBottomSheetBehavior = BottomSheetBehavior.from(gallery);

        mBottomSheetBehavior.setBottomSheetCallback(new BottomSheetBehavior.BottomSheetCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onStateChanged(@NonNull View bottomSheet, final int newState) {
                if (newState == BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_COLLAPSED) {
                    mBottomSheetBehavior.setPeekHeight(100);
                }

                if (newState == BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_DRAGGING) {

                    mBottomSheetBehavior.setState(BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_EXPANDED);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onSlide(@NonNull View bottomSheet, float slideOffset) {
            }
        });
        mBottomSheetBehavior.setPeekHeight(100);
```

I have seen similar answers on **stackOverFlow** such as:

```
gallery.setOnScroll(...)
if(!canScrollVertically(-1)) //Collapse
or checking if I'm on the top of gridview //Collapse
```

these answers works fine but the problem if I scroll up down speedily I can't see the top of gridview and it collapses.

so any advice please,
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to checkout [AndroidSwipeLayout](https://github.com/daimajia/AndroidSwipeLayout) library which have many collapse /expand  features and easy to use .

Answer (score 0):

i have the same problem, after research i found the code doing all the job.

put:

```
android:nestedScrollingEnabled="true"
```

in your xlm GridView